# Python: Find which version of a function I'm using

Tags: python, introspection, import

I'm a little confused with my imports and I'd like to see which version of a function I'm using. Is there some way to get the filename where the implementation or the class the holds it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module from standard Python library

```
import inspect


inspect.getfile(some_func)
```

Comment: Very nice! Didn't know of this. It does seem to fail on more functions (such as `struct.pack`) than just consulting `sys.modules` though.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen, `sys.modules[struct.pack.__module__].__file__` raising `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'` for me. Looks like there is no way to handle builtins `sys.modules[struct.pack.__module__]` -> `<module '_struct' (built-in)>`

Comment: I guess it must be a version or platform difference then. Luckily you shouldn't really need to know which file a built-in is coming from anyways.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen, I agree with you. btw, tested on Python 2.7.1 win32.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for most functions. It won't work for built-ins, but you're not importing those anyways.

```
import sys
sys.modules[somefunc.__module__].__file__
```

Comment: Not sure if this works with member functions: for example, `''.strip.__module__` is `None`.

Comment: @aix: That's because it's a built-in.